# Is there a way to programmatically get the List View Threshold in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-search

I'm working in an environment that has 4 different SharePoint implementations. All 4 environments run the same chunk of code, but the List View Threshold is not configured to the same value, which results in some searches exceeding the threshold while others run without problems.

Is there a way to find the value of the threshold programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, yes.
Asking The Google for the same thing in PowerShell gave me enough clues to figure out this line of code : `SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication.MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation`